# In circuit debug Interface communication with Windows

Tags: microcontroller, drivers, texas-instruments

I am trying to understand how TIVA123 processor communicates to windows. I see it does not require any com port and works on In circuit debug interface. Also on the download command I see download utility has arm-none-eabi-objcopy which does not require com port flags. How does it calculate which com port to connect to?

Comment: Do you mean comms for debugging or just for general purpose comms for getting data in and out?

Comment: I meant comms for debugging. I resolved the issue. I got to know that: UPDATE IN CIRCUIT DEBUG INTERFACE UNDER PORT AND ALL THESE DRIVERS WILL GET INSTALLED. TivaC indeed uses HID as the programming interface. lm4flash currently only supports one TivaC board being connected and it detects that board automatically without knowing the serial port.